# Theorems on finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

The Abstract Alegbra Precis has following theorems

**Theorem 3**. If G is a finite Abelian Group, and **p** is a prime dividing o(G), then G has a subgroup of order **p**.
**Theoerm 4**. If G is a finite Abelian Group and **k**. divides |G|, then G has a subroup of order **k** 
What is the difference between these two? Doesnt **Theorem 4** cover **Theorem 3** cases? Does **Theorem 3** cover any other special cases?

Comment: Yes for finite abelian group theorem 4 covers theorem 3.But theorem 3 holds for any finite group (not necessarily abelian) and it is called cauchy's Theorem.Theorem 4 may not holds for non abelian group

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Theorem $3$ is a particular case of Theorem $4$. However, Theorem $3$ is a particular case of [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) which is quite important on the study of finite groups. So, probably, it is stated as a Theorem by itself (and not as a Lemma for proving Theorem 4 nor a Corollary) because of its importance.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.